# How to get UV layer data by layer name?

Tags: python, uv

I have a code that works with this line:

```
uv_layer = blender_mesh_object.data.uv_layers[0]
```

But I need to expand this for 2 more UV layers with the names "lightmap" and "data", they both are optional so knowing the layer name is mandatory. I tried to get a layer with the name but got a KeyError.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Check if layer name exists
"lightmap" in blender_mesh_object.data.uv_layers

# Get layer by name (raises KeyError if doesn't exist)
blender_mesh_object.data.uv_layers["lightmap"]

# Get layer by name (None if doesn't exist)
blender_mesh_object.data.uv_layers.get("lightmap")
```